# Django: m2o relation to a m2m table

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, many-to-one

I have a default m2m relationship between Stage and Pipeline (without through model).
I have another model (StageHistory) that needs a m2o relationship with the data saved on the table created by the m2m relationship stage-pipeline.

So what i should write on "pipeline_stage" field ?

```
class Stage(models.Model):
    #other fields

class Pipeline(models.Model):
    stages = models.ManyToManyField('Stage')
    #other fields


class StageHistory(models.Model):
    pipeline_stage = models.ForeignKey(HERE)
```

Should I create a "through" model ?

Comment: Did you really understood the problem? I want a m2o between StageHistory and the m2m created by Stage - Pipeline.

I don't want a m2o between stagehistory and pipeline as you suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `Pipeline.stages.through` to reference the through table.

If not, you could use an [explicit through table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) and use that as the FK target.

Comment: I'm going to use the explicit through table. Thanks